# Insert midnight entry into Log

Tags: r, datetime, logging

We are monitoring 3 processes A, B and C that will always either be in level X, Y or Z. A protocol records when a process changes levels.

```
df = read.csv(tc <- textConnection('Time1,Process1,Level1
2013-01-09 18:00:34,A,X
2013-01-09 18:00:34,B,Y
2013-01-09 18:00:34,C,X
2013-01-09 22:00:59,A,Z
2013-01-10 00:10:38,A,X
2013-01-10 18:38:35,B,Z
2013-01-11 05:03:11,A,Z
2013-01-11 11:09:10,C,Y
2013-01-11 12:01:18,A,Off
2013-01-11 12:01:18,B,Off
2013-01-11 12:01:18,C,Off
'),header=TRUE)
close.connection(tc) 
df$Time1 = as.POSIXct(df$Time1)
```

Monitoring was started at 2013-01-09 18:00:34 and switched off at 2013-01-11 12:01:18. Between 2013-01-09 18:00:34 and 2013-01-09 22:00:59 process A was in level X, between 2013-01-09 22:00:59 and 2013-01-10 00:10:38 process A was in level Z.

For charting purposes, we would like to insert the last and first level state for each process for each midnight into the protocol:

```
2013-01-09 23:59:59,A,Z
2013-01-10 00:00:00,A,Z
2013-01-10 23:59:59,A,X
2013-01-11 00:00:00,A,X

2013-01-09 23:59:59,B,Y
2013-01-10 00:00:00,B,Y
2013-01-10 23:59:59,B,Z
2013-01-11 00:00:00,B,Z

2013-01-09 23:59:59,C,X
2013-01-10 00:00:00,C,X
2013-01-10 23:59:59,C,X
2013-01-11 00:00:00,C,X
```

It's ok to assume that there is not event in the log between 23:59:59 and 00:00:00. Finally, the protocol will be sorted by Time1 after insertion (that we can figure out ourselves). Any guidance is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(+1) Quite intricate and interesting task. I think I have the answer. I'll try to explain the method here. I hope it makes sense. There are two tricky bits here. My solution uses `data.table`.

`First:` I found it easier to construct first, the first two columns of the output that you require. This is done in the first part of the code shown below:

```
require(data.table)
dates <- unique(as.character(strptime(as.character(df$Time1), "%Y-%m-%d")))
dates <- dates[1:(length(dates)-1)]
dates <- strptime(paste(dates, "23:59:59"), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
dates <- sort(c(dates, dates+1))
Time <- rep(dates, length(levels(df$Process1)))
Process <- rep(levels(df$Process1), each=length(dates))
dt.out <- data.table(Time=as.POSIXct(Time), Process=Process)
# data.table outputs crazy values if not converted using as.POSIXct..?!
```

This should be straightforward to understand by looking at what each line of code does. I hope its extendable for other scenarios.

`Second:` The second bit is equally tricky, but it could be accomplished in one line using `data.table`. It took a while to figure out, but its awesome!

```
dt <- data.table(df, key="Process1") # convert input data.frame to data.table
out <- dt.out[, dt[J(Process)]$Level1[max(which(dt[J(Process)]$Time1 < Time))], 
            by = c("Process", "Time")]

> out

    Process                Time V1
 1:       A 2013-01-09 23:59:59  Z
 2:       A 2013-01-10 00:00:00  Z
 3:       A 2013-01-10 23:59:59  X
 4:       A 2013-01-11 00:00:00  X
 5:       B 2013-01-09 23:59:59  Y
 6:       B 2013-01-10 00:00:00  Y
 7:       B 2013-01-10 23:59:59  Z
 8:       B 2013-01-11 00:00:00  Z
 9:       C 2013-01-09 23:59:59  X
10:       C 2013-01-10 00:00:00  X
11:       C 2013-01-10 23:59:59  X
12:       C 2013-01-11 00:00:00  X
```

Let me break these two lines into parts to explain what's happening.

In the first line,  we `set key` for `dt` as `Process1`. This allows `VERY fast` filtering of the data by column `Process1`. That is, `dt["A"]` is equivalent to `df[df$Process1 == "A"]`, but the former is blazing fast.

In the second line, quite a lot of things are happening. We already created `dt.out` with the first two columns of the output required. All that remains is the third column. Look at the last part of the line that says `by = c("Process", "Time")`. Here, we are splitting `data.table dt.out` by these two variables. And to each one of the split `data.table`, we apply `dt[J(Process)]$Level1[max(which(dt[J(Process)]$Time1 < Time))]` which basically picks out the `maximum index` from all the current `Time1` values that are < `Time` from the `data.table` filtered by `Process` and uses this maximum index to return the corresponding `Levels1` value.

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 But this feels like a job for `roll=TRUE` e.g. just `dt[dt.out,roll=TRUE]` where both `dt` and `dt.out` are keyed by `'Process,Time'`. Didn't test, but something close to that?

Comment: Thanks @Arun. I learned a lot from you post and too enjoyed the problem. I implemented `First:` like you suggest and used a `for`-loop for `Second:`. Not pretty, but on a large data-set, it seemes faster than your solution. I'll play around a bit more with `data.table`.

Comment: @Arun, thanks for the assessment. Sharing the data would be difficult, unfortunately. It's about 3,000 rows over 2.5 days, about 30 processes and 10 levels. Getting more. Some processes with much more activity than others. The fact that `df` is sorted benefits the `for`-loop. Let me play with your solution again tomorrow or in the next days...

Comment: Happy to help Arun if you've got errors, it can get a bit tricky with scoping. `roll=TRUE` should be a significant speedup since as the current answer stands, `j` is getting evaluated for each 1-row group of `dt.out`, iiuc. That's a new call to the two `[.data.table` calls in `j` each time, with associated overhead, argument checking etc. Replacing it all with one `roll=TRUE` join would be one single join in bulk instead.   `i` doesn't have to be keyed for a `roll` join but it helps speed if it is as well.

Comment: @Arun: I left the project on Friday and no longer have access to the data. The final script may not have been totally pretty, but it was working alright. I'm still interested in exploring the `data.table` package further, but my priorities right now have shifted and like you I'll be fabricating a new dataset first. Again, I appreciate the interest you have shown in this problem very much!